# input タグ multiple 属性で選択させた複数のファイルを、個別のクエリパラメータに分けて送信したい

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, sastruts

```
<input file="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
```

によって複数選択されたファイル(例として5つ選択されたとします)を

```
<input file="file" name="files[0]" />
<input file="file" name="files[1]" />
<input file="file" name="files[2]" />
<input file="file" name="files[3]" />
<input file="file" name="files[4]" />
```

のように Javascript 等で分割して、 form を submit することは可能でしょうか。

サーバサイド( SAStruts で構築)の都合で  `multiple`属性 が設定されたフォームの入力を
受け取ることができません・・・。

以下経緯になります。

1. `multiple`属性を設定することで可能になる複数ファイル選択は利用したい
2. しかし SAStruts だと `multiple`属性 が設定された　`input="file"` を配列、または `List` で受け取ろうとしてもできない(実現する方法が見つからなかった, 分割した形式であれば受信できた)
3. なので Javascript で、複数ファイルが選択されたタイミングで `multiple`属性が設定された `input="file"` を分割しようと思った

という流れです。

解決方法として

1. 上記の経緯の通りに、 `input="file"` を分割する
2. 何かしらの方法で SAStruts で `multiple`属性 が設定されている `input="file"` を受信する
3. そもそも不可能で、分割する前に複数のmultipleが設定されていない `input="file"` を用意する

このいずれかの方法に関してご存知の方いましたらアドバイスいただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。(このアプリケーションでは jQuery も併せて利用しています。)

Comment: `<input file="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />`
とかぎかっこを付けるのはどうでしょう。　パラメータが変わるかもしれません。 受け取れるかは別問題ですが…

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
 name="file[]" で試してみたところ、 name="file" のときとは別のエラーが発生し、やはり受信できませんでした。 PHP であればそれで配列が取得できるんですが、SAStruts だと複数同名の input があれば自動で配列に入れてくれるみたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな感じでしょうか `#my_input`から`.input_0`~とかに振り分けます

```
var files = $("#my-input")[0].files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    $(".input_"+i)[0].files = files;
    $(".input_"+i)[0].files[0] = files[i];
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
上記のjavascriptのコード自体はエラーなく動作するのですが、submitしてみると、実際の$(".input_")には何も選択されていないようです・・・(指定したnameの中身を見ても空だった為)

Comment: fileListを初期化しないといけなかったですね。（が、fileListの初期化方法はよくしらない）ちょっと更新してみましたのでお試しください。

Comment: 試してみたのですが、`$(".input_"+i)[0].files = files;`で初期化はされるものの、`$(".input_"+i)[0].files[0] = files[i];`が反映されず、FileListは配列ではないのでspliceもできず・・・でした・・・。調べてみたところ [リンク1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632629/how-to-change-the-file-inputs-filelist)や[リンク2](http://p2b.jp/2010/07/27/inflexible-HTML5-File-API)にあるように、FileListはreadonlyのようで、参照はできても変更はできないみたいですね、無念です・・・。FileListの新しいインスタンスをjavascriptで作成できればよさそうですが、それも見当たらず・・・、でした・・・。

この問題解決は難しいかもしれませんが、非常に勉強になりました。
本当にありがとうございます。